# Using Wolfram to convert a value chart into graph

Tags: wolfram-alpha

Is it possible to use Wolfram Alpha to make something like this into a graph and have it display the proper function?

[image]

In that case, how would I syntactically write it in Wolfram?

Comment: Can you see what the proper function is yourself? It isn't too hard.

Comment: Yes xD, I'm just using this as an example.

Comment: If you have a large amount of data, you might try WolframAlpha Pro, which has allows you to upload files and has an Excel-like entry mode. If you're curious, I could post an answer with screenshots.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to plot the points, then you can use

> ```
> plot {{1, 12}, {3, 36}, {5, 60}, {7, 84}, {9, 108}}
> ```

[image]

If you want to try and approximate the function, then you can use

> ```
> interpolate {{1, 12}, {3, 36}, {5, 60}, {7, 84}, {9, 108}}
> ```

[image]

Of course, this isn't going to give you the exact function that you're looking for every time (this happens to be a nice example), but it will give an approximate polynomial based upon the data that you feed in.

Comment: Nice. As you note, these points just happen to be collinear. You might also try `fit`, rather than `interpolate`, particularly when the points are not collinear.